# Windows 2008 r2 Netlogon & sysvol

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, netlogon, sysvol

I have recently added 2008R2 server in my existing environment. I have 2 existing DC's before adding this one.
But, Netlogon & Sysvol folders not showing in this new DC. Although, DNS & AD replication is working fine.

Thanks,
Sandesh

Comment: check event logs see if it says why.

Comment: Event Id 13508 flooding with lots of warning about FRS service.

Comment: Can you post one of those log entries

Comment: Below is the Event Log ---                                                               The File Replication Service is having trouble enabling replication from SPORTZ.sportzinteractive.com to SPORTZ2 for c:\windows\sysvol\domain using the DNS name SPORTZ.sportzinteractive.com. FRS will keep retrying

Comment: chekc dns. can you resolve SPORTZ.sportzinteractive.com.?

Comment: Yes, able to resolve SPORTZ DC. And no issues with ping as well..

Comment: Please post the result of dcdiag /q. And what do you mean by you HAD two DCs? What happened with them? Did you remove them properly?

Comment: Sorry!! I corrected my original post.   Warning: DsGetDcName returned information for
 \\SPORTZ.sportzinteractive.com, when we were trying to reach SPORTZ2
 SERVER IS NOT RESPONDING or IS NOT CONSIDERED SUITABLE.
 SPORTZ2 failed test Advertising
 Error SPORTZINTERACTI\Enterprise Read-only Domain Controllers doesn'
 have
    Replicating Directory Changes In Filtered Set
 access rights for the naming context:
 CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=sportzinteractive,DC=com
SPORTZ2 failed test NCSecDesc
 Unable to connect to the NETLOGON share! (\\SPORTZ2\netlogon)

Comment: Any one have thought to share here please?

Comment: Actually, if `SYSVOL` isn't replicating to your new domain controller, that's absolute proof-positive that AD replication is not working properly. Or that you haven't promoted this DC properly... but either way, you need to troubleshoot why the replication isn't working to this DC, and fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep having issues with the AD replication try the burflag method.

http://www.bostonit.com/KnowledgeBase-Links-Articles/Reinitializing-Forcing-File-Replication-Service-using-Registry-key-BurFlags-D4.html

It is easy to do and straight forward - do it out of office hours though.